# Calling a multistage capistrano task from within a capistrano task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have a capistrano task that consolidates the deployment of multiple stages of a Rails project.

For example:

```
task :consolidated_task do
    build #creates a new release branch from master, 
          #sets a variable with the relese branch name

    staging
    deploy.migrations

    production
    deploy.migrations
end
```

Is this the proper way to call a multistage task from another cap task?

The build task creates a new git branch and published it. The name of the new branch gets saved as a capistrano variable. the staging and production stage tasks then use this variable to specify what branch to deploy from.

When this task runs, it fails with:

```
fatal: working tree '/Users/<my working directory>' already exists.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb:99:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /var/folders/3d/3dKYNUwQGOSLZFXsMF-uv++++TM/-Tmp-/20100802182750/REVISION (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I'm pushing the source from my local machine as the git repository and the deployment machine cannot communicate with each other.

Comment: Now it's at 100%. I must be a power user!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Task names like

```
deploy:production:whatever
```

are exposed within Cap as

```
deploy.production.whatever
```

You also have `top` namespaces to go to the top of the namespaces, because the paths are relative.

So, no matter in which namespace your task currently is you can always do thigs like:

```
top.deploy.production.whatever
```