# How to run a capistrano task on another stage?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

My root capistrano has a task that dumps the database: `cap production dump` or `cap staging dump` will dump the database.

Now, I want to define a task in staging that will run this task on production.

I could do

```
desc 'Updates the database of acceptance with the latest production database'
task :update_db do
  run_locally do
    execute :cap, 'production', 'dump'
    # move dump-file from production, via local, to acceptance
  end
  on roles(:db) do
    execute :rake, 'db:data:load'
  end
end
```

But running a cap task from a cap task via a shell feels ugly and
fragile.

I found
[Calling a multistage capistrano task from within a capistrano task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390895/calling-a-multistage-capistrano-task-from-within-a-capistrano-task)
but that does not work, probably because its a solution for an old
version of Capistrano.

Is there a way to run a certain capistrano task on a certain "stage"
from within Capistrano?

Comment: I walked through the source code for a little while and don't think this is possible… Really good idea though.